# create an x-dim array using numpy.fromfunction from a function with more than x parameters

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to create a 2D (x,y) array from a 5d function, say some kernel KMID:

```
import numpy as np
def KMID(x,y,mumid,delta,cmid):
    rsq=(x-float(len(x))/2.+0.5)**2+(y-float(len(y))/2.+0.5)**2
    return cmid*np.exp(-mumid*np.sqrt(rsq))/(rsq+delta**2)
```

by something like this:

```
shape=256,256
midscatterkernel=np.fromfunction(KMID(:,:,0.1,0.2,0.3),shape)
```

This gives:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

i.e. I want to make a 2D array by iterating over just the first two indices. 
What is the most elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`KMID` is a function, not an array, so you can't index it with `:`. Do

```
midscatterkernel=np.fromfunction(lambda x, y: KMID(x,y,0.1,0.2,0.3), shape)
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `np.fromfunction` for this, since `KMID` can accept numpy arrays as arguments:

```
import numpy as np

def KMID(x, y, mumid, delta, cmid):
    rsq = (x-len(x)/2.+0.5)**2+(y-len(y)/2.+0.5)**2
    return cmid*np.exp(-mumid*np.sqrt(rsq))/(rsq+delta**2)

lenx, leny = 256, 256
midscatterkernel = KMID(
    np.arange(lenx),
    np.arange(leny)[:, np.newaxis],
    0.1, 0.2, 0.3)
```

(`np.fromfunction` is syntactic sugar for a slow Python loop. If you can do the same thing with numpy array operations, use the numpy array operations. It will be faster.)

---

To answer you question, however, if you did need to use `np.fromfunction`, but wanted to supply some of the arguments as constants, then you could use `functools.partial`:

```
import functools
def KMID(x, y, mumid, delta, cmid):
    rsq = (x-len(x)/2.+0.5)**2+(y-len(y)/2.+0.5)**2
    return cmid*np.exp(-mumid*np.sqrt(rsq))/(rsq+delta**2)

shape = 256, 256
midscatterkernel = np.fromfunction(functools.partial(KMID,mumid=0.1,delta=0.2,cmid=0.3),shape)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on np.fromfunction and how to avoid using it, I didn't know it was slow.